# How to display the time result with 24 hour calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

For example, server time is 15:00:00. I run the following query but it gives me wrong result. Here my query

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '08:00:01' AND '10:00:00' 
         THEN 1 
      WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '14:00:01' AND '08:00:00' 
         THEN 2 
      ELSE 0 
    END AS IdShift
```

What's wrong with my query ? from that case my expected result is 2. but it give me 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `BETWEEN` clause you have to specify the lower value first, then the higher value.
So you have to change `BETWEEN '14:00:01' AND '08:00:00'` to `BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '14:00:01'`.

When you want to span from `14:00` to **the next day** `08:00` you have to include the date.

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN NOW() BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 08:00:01') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 10:00:00')
         THEN 1 
      WHEN NOW() BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 14:00:01') AND CONCAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, ' 08:00:00')
         THEN 2 
      ELSE 0 
    END AS IdShift
```

Comment: what if there are more than 2 conditions. for example -> 08:00:00 - 17:00:00 as 1, 17:00:01 - 00:30:00 as 2,  00:30:01 - 07:59:59 as 3

Comment: You can add as many `WHEN`s as you want. Sorry, I don't get what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, for `between` the lower bound is always first.  I'm not a fan of `between`, but you need to split your conditions:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '08:00:01' AND '10:00:00' 
             THEN 1 
             WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '14:00:01' AND '23:59:59' 
             THEN 2
             WHEN TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '08:00:00' 
             THEN 2 
             ELSE 0 
        END) AS IdShift
```

Or, phrase this with `or`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TIME(NOW()) > '08:00:00' AND TIME(NOW()) <= '10:00:00' 
             THEN 1 
             WHEN TIME(NOW()) > '14:00:00' OR TIME(NOW()) < '08:00:00' 
             THEN 2
             ELSE 0 
        END) AS IdShift
```

I would be inclined to shift the logic by a minute or two and use hours:

```
(case when hour(now()) >= 8 and hour(now()) < 10
      then 1
      when hour(now()) >= 14 or hour(now()) < 8
      then 2
 end)
```